# Problema al ingresar datos de entrada por consola con el metodo readline de node js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, consola

estoy tratando de almacenar un dato de entrada ingresado por consola por parte del usuario en una variable con el metodo readline de node js para luego usar esa variable en otro codigo pero estoy teniendo el siguiente problema al ejecutar el codigo:

```
const readline= require('readline')
                ^
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\HUGO BUSTAMANTE\AppData\Local\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Curso de angular\Reto MachEight\reto js\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///C:/Users/HUGO%20BUSTAMANTE/AppData/Local/Programs/xampp/htdocs/Curso%20de%20angular/Reto%20MachEight/reto%20js/app.js:4:17      
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:197:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
```

Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
//Funcion donde quiero utilizar el dato ingresado por el usuario:
function printPlayers(){
fetch('https://mach-eight.uc.r.appspot.com')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(({values}) => {
    const sum140 = []
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i+1; j < values.length; j++) {
            if(Number.parseInt(values[i].h_in, 10) + Number.parseInt(values[j].h_in, 10) === numero){//ACÁ UTILIZO EL DATO INGRESADO.
                sum140.push([values[i], values[j]])
            }
        }
    }
  console.log(sum140);
})
}

printPlayers();
```

Agradezco de ante mano si alguien conoce la solucion al error, pues quiero almacenar un numero en una variable ingresado por consola y que dependiendo de ese numero se ejecute la condicion del if, osea está linea de codigo:

```
if(Number.parseInt(values[i].h_in, 10) + Number.parseInt(values[j].h_in, 10) === numero){//ACÁ UTILIZO EL DATO INGRESADO.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando la importación usando módulos, por lo que no puedes usar `require`. Importa los módulos usando `import`:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import readline from 'readline';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'node:process';


function printPlayers() {
    fetch('https://mach-eight.uc.r.appspot.com')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(({ values }) => {
            const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });
            rl.question('Inserte el número deseado:   ', (numero) => {
                const number = Number.parseInt(numero);
                const pairs = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    for (let j = i + 1; j < values.length; j++) {
                        const h1 = Number.parseInt(values[i].h_in)
                        const h2 = Number.parseInt(values[j].h_in)
                        if (h1 + h2 === number) {//ACÁ UTILIZO EL DATO INGRESADO.
                            pairs.push([values[i], values[j]])
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(pairs);
                rl.close();
            });
        })
}

printPlayers();
```

Alternativamente usando promesas:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import { createInterface } from 'readline';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'node:process';
import { promisify } from 'util'

const readline = createInterface({ input, output })
readline.question[promisify.custom] = (question) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        readline.question(question, resolve);
    });
};

function printPlayers() {
    fetch('https://mach-eight.uc.r.appspot.com')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(async ({ values }) => {
            const numeroString = await promisify(readline.question)('Inserte el numero:   ');
            const numero = parseInt(numeroString);
            const pairs = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                for (let j = i + 1; j < values.length; j++) {
                    const h1 = Number.parseInt(values[i].h_in)
                    const h2 = Number.parseInt(values[j].h_in)
                    if (h1 + h2 === numero) {//ACÁ UTILIZO EL DATO INGRESADO.
                        pairs.push([values[i], values[j]])
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(pairs);
            readline.close();
        })
}

printPlayers();
```

Comment: Gracias!, me funciono